# How to use doom emacs as a golang ide quickly?

Tags: shell, doom, environment, path, golang

I installed the newest doom emacs on macOS. Also configed language packages as

```
$ emacs ~/.doom.d/init.el
:lang
(go +lsp)
:tools
lsp

$ ~/.emacs.d/bin/doom sync
```

When I open a .go file, the code became highlight. But after save the file, the code can't been formated automatically.
I have installed `gofmt` and `goimports`. How to set emacs to use them?

I read this document: [lang/go](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/lang/go/README.org) module.
It seems it can do it: `Auto-formatting on save (gofmt)`. Maybe because of environment path? So how to call system path from emacs?
My `GOPATH` is `~/go`, it set in `~/.zshrc`. When I open `shell` via `M+x`, something is different from terminal. How to import `.zshrc` configuration completely?

Comment: Try running `gofmt` from `M-x` and check this GitHub issue, someone posted a config where it will enable gofmt on save https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/4201

Answer (score 0):

In your doom init.el file you need to enable format +onsave in the :editor section. See the snippet below or look at the example init.el (with format +onsave disabled) on the [doom emacs git repo](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/init.example.el#L58)

> 

```
   :editor
   (evil +everywhere); come to the dark side, we have cookies
   file-templates    ; auto-snippets for empty files
   fold              ; (nigh) universal code folding
   (format +onsave)  ; automated prettiness
   ;;god               ; run Emacs commands without modifier keys
   ;;lispy             ; vim for lisp, for people who don't like vim
   ;;multiple-cursors  ; editing in many places at once
   ;;objed             ; text object editing for the innocent
   ;;parinfer          ; turn lisp into python, sort of
   ;;rotate-text       ; cycle region at point between text candidates
   snippets          ; my elves. They type so I don't have to
   ;;word-wrap         ; soft wrapping with language-aware indent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ emacs ~/.doom.d/init.el

:editor
(evil +everywhere)
(format +onsave)

:lang
(go +lsp)

:tools
lsp

$ ~/.emacs.d/bin/doom sync
```

Keys:

- use `SPC p s` to format and save all project's buffers
- use `SPC c o` to auto-remove from Go `import ()` (or auto-add, but it mostly happens as you edit text)
- use `SPC m i z z` to jump to the Go `imports ()` block
- use `C-o` to jump back (I'm not sure how this works so far)

There is no integration between `import ()` and the `go mod`. For example adding a new package, does not add the corresponding module.